# How do I take multiple words and output a combined version, where each word is separated by a dollar sign $ using ECMA6?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> You are making a text encryptor. It should take multiple words and
> output a combined version, where each word is separated by a dollar
> sign `$`. For example, for the words "hello", "how", "are", "you", the
> output should be "$hello$how$are$you$". The given code declares a
> class named `Add`, with a constructor that takes one rest parameter.
> Complete the code by adding a `print()` method to the class, which
> should generate the requested output.

My code:

```
class Add {
      constructor(...words)      {
              
this.words = words;
  

}
 //What method to use and how?

   

}



var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");

var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");

var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");

x.print();

y.print();

z.print();
```

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/14853083

Answer (score 0):

If this.words is an array of words, then the print method would simply join the words together with a "$" separator as seen here in this code snippet:

```js
//My code :

class Add {
      constructor(...words)      {
              
this.words = words;
  

}
 //What method to use and how?
print(){
  console.log('$' + this.words.join('$') + '$')
}
   

}



var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");

var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");

var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");

x.print();

y.print();

z.print();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,can you suggest me some link or youtube vids which can help me to grasp more on ECMA6?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {        
    this.words = words;
  }
 //What method to use and how?
  print(divider = '$') {
    console.log(`${divider}${this.words.join(divider)}${divider}`);
  }
}

var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");

x.print();
// $hehe$hoho$haha$hihi$huhu$
y.print();
// $this$is$awesome$
z.print();
// $lorem$ipsum$dolor$sit$amet$consectetur$adipiscing$elit$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,can you suggest me some link or youtube vids which can help me to grasp more on ECMA6?

Comment: @RKEshat Start with The Net Ninja [channel] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Mp2kwE8xY0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gKfw25slm4CUDUcM_sXdml)